# SIP clients not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sip

I am trying to find a SIP client that works on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have an account on voipdiscount (www.voipdiscount.com) and 12voip (www.12voip.com) Earlier on Ubuntu 11.10, I was able to use SIP clients: Twinkle, SFL Phone. Using these clients, I was able to access my account and make the phone calls to different destinations.

But after I installed 12.04, Twinkle, SFL Phone and Ekiga stopped. Whenever I try to make a phone call using one of these software, for some reason they are not able to register. They are failing. 
Any suggestions as to what I can do? Is there any SIP client that works on Ubuntu 12.04?

Thanks!

Comment: What sflphone release have you tried?

Comment: Try blink you can get it [here](http://icanblink.com)
its easy to use

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. As a solution until I find in the Linux community, I am using http://www.phoner.de/index_en.htm and http://www.phonerlite.de/index_en.htm with wine. It works pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

What's the deal with these Wine solutions?

SFL Phone works fine when installed from the dev repo, at least on Mint Maya (12.04-based) but I had difficulties with Lubuntu Precise.

Linphone should work like a charm, but it can be a bit of a hog, especially when conferencing.

Twinkle works great under Mint Maya and Lubuntu Precise

Your problem might be SIP-related. Are you reusing your old settings or did you reenter them from scratch? Check which codecs you provider uses and push them up to the top of the list. Experiment with various authentication usernames (is it just "username" or "username@registrar"?) Any of these things could create authentication difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Here are instructions on how to set up Blink in Ubuntu 13. Hopefully they are the same for Ubuntu 12.

https://gist.github.com/juampy72/6578111

Comment: It is recommended that atleast a summary be provided here. Answers with just links are discouraged on Ask Ubuntu.